# True memory usage of my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory

Which memory usage reporting method should I use when my application crashes due to low memory? There are few options:

- *Allocations* instrumentation tool
- *Activity Monitor* instrumentation tool
- *VM Tracker* instrumentation tool
- Xcode debugging sessions memory reporting
- *mach_msg_type_number_t.resident_size*

The problem is that every method returns different results.

Allocations instrumentation return much smaller values than other methods - I assume Allocation only counts memory explicitly allocated inside application, but not memory used by my my app code and other libraries code? Am I right? On 512MB devices Allocation reports as low as 70MB of allocated memory and application still receives memory warnings and eventually crashes. Can I somehow measure what this difference is exactly?

Xcode debugging sessions memory reporting and *mach_msg_type_number_t.resident_size* varies vastly. They are sometimes 50MB away from each other, both ways. Why is that?